# static properties and instances

Tags: php, oop, static, instance

What will happen if I create a class with a `static` property and create two instances of it?

Will the `static` property be shared between both instances and not be duplicated?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, that is the definition of a [`static`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) property.

Static properties belong to the **class**, not **instances of the class**.

```
class SomeClass {
   private static $instanceCount = 0;

   function __construct() {
      self::$instanceCount++;
      //do other stuff.
   }

   function instanceCount() { 
      return self::$instanceCount;
   }

}

$one = new SomeClass();
echo $one->instanceCount(); //1    

$two = new SomeClass();

echo $one->instanceCount(); //2
echo $two->instanceCount(); //2
```